# Crear un arreglo y enviarlo a una vista

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

estaba intentando crear un arreglo con los datos que obtengo con distintas "querys" para poder enviarlo y recorrerlo en la vista y armar una tabla con esos datos, pero no se me ocurre como hacerlo, este es mi codigo por si alguien puede ayudarme con eso, estoy recien aprendiendo a usar laravel

```
public function index(){

    $mesActual = date('Ym').'01';
    $dataFechas = Modelo::where('flujo','like','%-18%-')
                                ->where('fecha','>=',$mesActual)
                                ->groupBy('fecha')
                                ->orderBy('fecha')
                                ->get('fecha')
                                ->toJson();
    //aqui obtengo la fecha para poder buscar los otros datos que necesito y los guardo en un json
    $fechas = json_decode($dataFechas, true);
    foreach ($fechas as $valor) {
        $fecha = $valor['fecha'];
        //aqui guardo la fecha para usarlas en las siguientes querys
        $data2 = Modelo::where('flujo','like','%18%')->where('fecha','=',$fecha)->get()->count();
        $data3 = Modelo::where('flujo','like','%18%')->where('fecha','=',$fecha)->where('estado_auditoria','=','Aprobado')->get()->count();
        $data4 = Modelo::where('flujo','like','%18%')->where('fecha','=',$fecha)->where('estado_auditoria','=','Rechazado')->get()->count();
        $data5 = 0;
        $data6 = 0;
        //guardo los datos en un arreglo
        $datos = ['fecha' => $fecha, 
                    'ventas' => $data2, 
                    'aprobadas' => $data3, 
                    'rechazadas' => $data4, 
                    'programadas' => $data5,
                    'no_auditadas' => $data6];
        print_r($datos);
    }
    // retornamos la vista con los datos
    return view('nom_vista.index')->with('$datos', $datos);

}
```

cuando guardo los datos en el arreglo, solo me envia el ultimo que se guardo y necesito enviar todos los que se recorren en el bucle
de antemano Gracias

Comment: Me parece muy *rebuscada* la forma en que planteas tu consulta y por ahí podriamos aportar la ayuda para mandar de forma mas simple los datos, ¿nos compartes exactamente lo que deseas obtener?

Comment: quiero armar un arreglo con los datos que obtengo de esas querys y enviarlo a la vista, de hecho habia intentado hacerlo todo en una sola query pero me parecio mas complicado

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo lo siguiente:

- Conviertas el resultado de tu primer consulta a json, solo déjala como una colección
- Declara todas tus variables, incluido el vector asociativo a llenar por fuera del foreach
- No transformes el vector antes de usarlo en el foreach
- Mientras que las variables son llenadas por dentro del foreach, el llenado del nuevo vector ocurre por fuera
- No hay necesidad de usar el método get si solo vas a obtener el conteo de los registros de dicha consulta, pues no planeas obtener colecciones
- Usa la instancia de Carbon a través del helper now para obtener el número de mes actual
- Si data 5 y 6 no se llenan con valores resultantes del ciclo foreach entonces no tiene caso que les des valor dentro de este, hazlo desde el inicio

Código:

```
$mesActual = now()->month;
$dataFechas = Modelo::select('fecha')
                    ->where('flujo','like','%-18%-')
                    ->whereMonth('fecha','>=',$mesActual)
                    ->groupBy('fecha')
                    ->orderBy('fecha')
                    ->get()

    $data2 = "";
    $data3 = "";
    $data4 = "";
    $data5 = 0;
    $data6 = 0;
    $datos = [];

    foreach ($dataFechas as $valor) 
    {
        $fecha = $valor["fecha"];
        //aqui guardo la fecha para usarlas en las siguientes querys
        $data2 = Modelo::where('flujo','like','%18%')
                        ->whereFecha($valor["fecha"])
                        ->count();
        $data3 = Modelo::where('flujo','like','%18%')
                        ->whereFecha($valor["fecha"])
                        ->whereEstadoAuditoria('Aprobado')
                        ->count();
        $data4 = Modelo::where('flujo','like','%18%')
                        ->where('fecha','=',$valor["fecha"])
                        ->whereEstadoAuditoria('Rechazado')
                        ->count();    
    }

    $datos = [  'fecha' => $fecha, 
                'ventas' => $data2, 
                'aprobadas' => $data3, 
                'rechazadas' => $data4, 
                'programadas' => $data5,
                'no_auditadas' => $data6];
    // retornamos la vista con los datos
    return view('nom_vista.index')->with(['$datos' => $datos]);
```